# Can I use “@” as a canonical name in the CNAME resource record?

Tags: bind

I have a CNAME RR which points to the same domain as defined in the $ORIGIN:

```
$TTL 604800
$ORIGIN example.com.
...
    IN A     10.0.0.5
www IN CNAME example.com.
```

Is it mandatory to specify the FQDN in the canonical name here, or can I use instead the following forms?

```
www IN CNAME @
```

or:

```
www IN CNAME
```

I checked *Pro DNS and BIND 10* by Ron Aitchison, as well as [the CNAME record article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record), and none explain if this is allowed or not (and both sources put a FQDN in the examples).

Comment: looks like nsd checkzone does allow me to do that, and properly resolves to origin. Interesting question though, I wasn't sure before trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Håkan remarks in a comment, the `@` and `$ORIGIN` directives are part of the original zone file format (cf. [Bind 9 manual](https://downloads.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.14.6/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch05.html#zone_directives) and [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035)).

The directives:

```
www IN CNAME @
```

and

```
www IN CNAME example.com.
```

are equivalent, assuming `$ORIGIN example.com.`.

Since the `$ORIGIN` directive is also optional in Bind 9, you can create a zone file without mentioning your FQDN even once.

Comment: `@` and `$ORIGIN` were part of the master file format as defined in [RFC1035](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035#section-5.1).

Comment: Whether `www IN CNAME @` and `www IN CNAME example.com.` are equivalent depends on the current origin; if the `$ORIGIN` directive has been used to redefine the origin, these are no longer equivalent.

Comment: I was assuming `$ORIGIN example.com` as in the OP's question. I corrected the statement about **RFC 1035**, thanks.